# Running 'cat' on a file opens the print dialog?

Tags: macos, printing, cat

On a whim today, I ran the 'cat' command on a VirtualBox virtual disk image (VDI) file. As expected, a variety of gibberish was output to the stdout on the console. However about 15 seconds into running the command, the print dialog opened! It displayed a page with just more machine code, ready to print. When I closed the dialog, the file continued on printing as usual.

I'm really mystified by this. I'm running macOS Sierra 10.12.6. Does anyone have any ideas how this kind of behavior can even happen?

Comment: If you `cat` a binary file, there is no knowing what terminal escape sequences you will trigger. You should check your terminal configuration to see if any escape sequences invoke a print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MacOS's *Terminal.app* does not appear to do this, but *iTerm2* responds to the printer control sequences supported by xterm.

From the command-line, you can do this using

```
tput mc0
```

which prints the contents of the screen, or

```
tput mc5
```

which turns the printer on.  The latter would be more annoying, so your *binary* file probably had the string corresponding to `mc0`:

<kbd>*Escape*</kbd><kbd>**`[`**</kbd><kbd>**`i`**</kbd>

(the sequence for `mc5` has a **`5`** before the **`i`**).

For reference:

- [*XTerm Control Sequences*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)

```
    CSI Pm i  Media Copy (MC).
                Ps = 0  -> Print screen (default).
                Ps = 4  -> Turn off printer controller mode.
                Ps = 5  -> Turn on printer controller mode.
```

- [**`terminfo`** - terminal capability data base](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html)

  Documents the names `mc0`, `mc5` and a few others.
- [**`tput`**, **`reset`** - initialize a terminal or query terminfo database](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html)